# Windows Server 2019 - RDP is not accepting valid user credentials

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2019

I have setup a fresh Windows Server 2019 installation on an ESXI host, and the WS2019 guest will only allow the Admin user to establish an RDP connection.

I have configured 2 additional users (so that we can stop sharing admin accounts!) and added said users to the admin group as well as the remote users group.

I have successfully logged in locally (via ESXI web console) to both of the new users, to account for some potential issues when logging in via RDP for the first time. This is how I know the passwords are working correctly.

I have also confirmed the requisite group+security+firewall policies, and assume they are as needed since the admin user can RDP successfully into the server.

So, what else could I be missing? Why would RDP deny a valid UN/PW set for users in the right groups?

["Credentials did not work"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8dxN.png)

Comment: you are probably forgot to add the username to the "Remote Desktop Users" security group. Admins automatically have the right to login remotely, users need to be in that local group...

Comment: @Martin I've added the 2 new users to both the admins group and the remote desktop users group already. That was an initial troubleshooting step.

Comment: You didn't actually tell us what happens when you try to log in via RDP. How about giving us those details?

Comment: @joeqwerty I just added an image with the error. Maybe I didn't describe that problem right. RDP will allow admin to login, but not the other users who are in the admin and remote users groups, and also have valid credentials that work to logon locally. That's what I meant by this:

"Why would RDP deny a valid UN/PW set for users in the right groups?"

Comment: do you have the remote desktop session host role installed on that server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't joined the guest win2019 server to an AD, Check you specified the username as either .\username or as servername\username in the rdclient

I believe 'Username' on its own defaults to using the client-pc or client-pc-domain as the user domain